# Opening built-in cheat sheet

Tags: help-system

Every now and then when I try to quit vim, I incidentally open window with command cheat sheet as in attached picture. How do I do this and how is it called?

[image]

Comment: If you want, you can use `nnoremap q: :q` to quit when you accidentally type `q:` instead of `:q`.

Comment: I like how all the commands in the command line window screenshot are concerned with quitting vim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's not a cheat sheet; it's a history of the commands you've executed. It allows you to find, edit and repeat commands you've previously executed. There are a couple of ways you can enter it. One is to type `Ctrl-F` while on the ex command line. Another way is to type `q:` while in normal mode. You can read more about it here:

```
:help 20.4
:help 20.5
:help cmdwin
```

Answer (score 5):

This is command history invoked by `q:`.

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_command-line_history